# How to make single property of an object function parameter generic?

Tags: typescript, object, parameters, typescript-generics

I have a generic function

```js
function test<T>(a: string, b: T, c: number)
```

But I would like the parameters to be a single object like so

```js
function test(params: {a: string; b: T, c: number})
```

I know I can make an object generic like this

```js
type MyObject<T> = {a: string; b: T, c: number}
```

But when I go to use that type as the parameter I don't know how to handle T

```js
function test(params: MyObject<T>) // Where do I define T?
```

My thinking is to somehow "destructure" the params type so that typescript knows which parameter to be generic, but I couldn't get it to work

```js
function test<{_, T, __}>(params: MyObject<T>) // Does not work as intended
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to combine the generic syntax in the function definition (`<T>`) with the parameter list. Only the one `b` property changes, so `{a: string; b: T, c: number}` is sufficient - `string` and `number` for the other properties is fine.

```
function test<T>(params: {a: string; b: T, c: number}) {
    
}
```

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense. My mentality was that params would be of type T but typescript overrides the properties that I explicitly define. Thanks